# Pod don't store data using PersistentVolume(PV) and PersistentVolumeClaim(PVC)

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, kubernetes, akka-http

I have created tow pods One is running a simple scala application, that uses akkaHttp to add user data into Elasticsearch and another Pod running an elasticsearch:8.4.5. Also created an external service for akka and internal service for elasticsearch. I can add data into ES using postman and get the data as well. Now I want to use Persistent-Volume to store the data even the pod die and recreated, here are my YAML files.

deployment.yaml (elasticsearch)

```
`apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elastic-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elastic-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: elastic-pod
      labels:
        app: elastic-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elastic-container
          image: elasticsearch:8.4.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
          env:
            - name: discovery.type
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.discovery.type
            - name: xpack.security.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.enabled
            - name: xpack.security.enrollment.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.enrollment.enabled
            - name: xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled
          volumeMounts:
            - name: elastic-storage
              mountPath: /storage/data
      volumes:
        - name: elastic-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: elastic-pvc`
```

PersistentVolume.yaml

```
`apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elastic-pv

spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: /storage/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - minikube`
```

PersistentVolumeClaim.yaml

```
`apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elastic-pvc

spec:
  volumeName: elastic-pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: ""
`
```

I'm able to add user data into elasticsearch, but when the pod restart the data also lost and get an  error

`An error occurred: [es/get] failed: [index_not_found_exception] no such index [user]`

Also the directory "/storage/data" inside minikube there is no file.

is there any problem with my YAML files?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually create PersistentVolumes, and in particular a `hostPath` volume can be unreliable in a clustered environment.  Minikube has a [basic persistent volume provisioner](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#dynamic-provisioning-and-csi) and you should rely on this.  Creating the PersistentVolumeClaim via a StatefulSet is probably a little better practice than mounting a volume into a potentially-replicated Deployment.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried with StatefulSet as well, I inserted the data, and when restart the pod, the pod data is lost as well which is not a required behaviour

Comment: You're mounting the volume on `/storage/data`, but looking at [the Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/docker.html#_always_bind_data_volumes) it looks like it should be at `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data`.

Comment: @DavidMaze i thing I'm asking something else, "I just want to use the PV in my app so that when the pod crashes or restart the data still remain there"

Comment: In the `volumeMounts:` section in the pod spec, I think you're mounting the volume to the wrong place, so it's not getting used.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze issued resloved with the help you you.